# How can I list all updates installed on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, updates

How can I list all updates installed on Mac OS X?

Comment: The way updates are recorded has changed considerably between versions of OS X; both of the answers I see os far apply to Snow Leopard (10.6), so if you're concerned with another version, please specify.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The list of all installed updates is located in `/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist`if you don't want to use the Software Update preference pane.

Comment: includes lots of additional software installed (or not) in addition to the stuff managed by the OS.

Comment: There's also `/var/db/receipts/`, which contains plist and bom files for most of the entries in `InstallHistory.plist`.

Answer (score 8):

System Prefs > Software Update > Installed Software.

Sort by date.

Comment: The tab for installed updates was removed on 10.8.

Answer (score 8):

Open the **System Information** application which can be found in **/Applications/Utilities**. Then go to **Software -> Installations** and there you have it.

This solution works on old and new versions of OS X (I've tested it on 10.8.2).

Answer (score 7):

Use the following command:

```
/usr/sbin/system_profiler SPInstallHistoryDataType
```

Which is the command line alternative to "System Profile"

Answer (score 4):

Do not rely on AppStore to tell you if you have the latest updates installed. It will lie to you.

Open the Terminal application and type the following and hit enter:

`softwareupdate --history`

Shows the Mac OS install history, including updates.  By default, only displays updates installed by `softwareupdate`.  To see all installs including Applications type the following and hit enter:

`softwareupdate --history --all`

Not sure if this works on older MacOS releases, but it works for High Sierra as of 10.13.4.